# Using geom_boxplot with quantiles

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Question

I'd like to use ggplot's `geom_boxplot` and use my own data columns for the quantile segments, instead of those returned by `stat_boxplot`.

The data, after doing some transformations, looks like this:

```
> allquartile                                                      
      T method       s.0%      s.25%      s.50%      s.75%     s.100%                                                                                                    
1     2    LDA -196.76273 -190.38842 -184.01411 -177.63979 -171.26548                                                                                                    
2     3    LDA -171.53987 -166.16923 -160.79859 -115.28652  -69.77446                                                                                                    
3     4    LDA -161.17590 -157.61372 -149.71026 -124.68926  -69.77446                                                                                                    
4     5    LDA -194.10553 -179.83165 -175.14337 -168.46104 -159.07206
```

After doing a lot of searching and digging, I figured out that my plotting command should look like this:

```
p <- ggplot(allquartile,aes(x=T, ymin=`s.0%`, lower=`s.25%`,
                            middle=`s.50%`, upper=`s.75%`,
                            ymax=`s.100%`, color=method)) + 
     geom_boxplot(stat="identity")
```

This *should* use s.0% as the min, s.25% as the lower, etc etc.  But when i try to display `p`, i get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 's.0%' not found                                                                                                             
Calls: print ... lapply -> is.vector -> lapply -> FUN -> eval -> eval
```

I've also tried using `aes_string` in place of `aes`, and I instead get this error:

```
Error in aes_string(x = T, ymin = `s.0%`, lower = `s.25%`, middle = `s.50%`,  :                                                                                            
object 's.0%' not found
```

I'm fairly new to both R and ggplot2, so i'm not realy sure how to interpret this, but I'm assuming it's because of the `.` in `s.0%`.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to get around this.

Edit: I've dug around more and I think this is due to my misunderstanding of the quantile method.  I created `allquartile` by this command:

```
allquartile <-aggregate(list(s=topicquality$score), list(T=topicquality$T,method=topicquality$method),FUN=quantile,probs=seq(0, 1, .25))
```

And I realize that there are no *columns* named `score.0%`, `score.25%`, etc.  There is just the `score` column with 5 values.  So this boils down to: how do i access those 5 values within `score`?

### SOLUTION

I've found the issue with my dataset.  As i mentioned in my edit, the columns `score.0%`, `score.25%`, etc didn't exist based on how i formed the data frame.  For example, running `colnames(allquartile)` returned:

```
[1] "T"      "method" "score"
```

It turns out that the `score` column is a vector of values.  Running `allquartile$score` gives me:

```
            0%       25%       50%       75%       100%
[1,] -196.7627 -190.3884 -184.0141 -177.6398 -171.26548
[2,] -171.5399 -166.1692 -160.7986 -115.2865  -69.77446
[3,] -161.1759 -157.6137 -149.7103 -124.6893  -69.77446
[4,] -194.1055 -179.8316 -175.1434 -168.4610 -159.07206
[5,] -200.1544 -174.2835 -167.7209 -145.3432 -129.54586
```

I can then access each individual quantile's values by doing

```
> allquartile$score[,1]
[1] -196.7627 -171.5399 -161.1759 -194.1055 -200.1544
```

I'm not familiar with R enough to know what kind of data structure this is, but I would call it a matrix.  So like any good matrix object, `m[,column]` returns the values of the column while `m[row,]` returns the values of the row, and `m[row, column]` gets the cell value.

With that in mind, I've realized that the propper plotting command should be

```
p <- ggplot(allquartile,
            aes(x=T,
                ymin=score[,1],
                lower=score[,2],
                middle=score[,3],
                upper=score[,4], 
                ymax=score[,5], 
                color=method)) + 
     geom_boxplot(stat="identity")
```

And this plots out everything perfectly.

Thanks to everyone for the good suggestions, even though they didn't fix the problem, they helped a lot in figuring things out.

Comment: The `.` probably isn't a problem, but I'd bet the `%` is. Try reading `?make.names`.

Comment: I thought that was well, but I found an example where 

    `p <- ggplot(data,aes(x=.id, ymin=\`5%\`, lower=\`25%\`, middle=\`50%\`, upper=\`75%\`, ymax=\`95%\`)) + geom_boxplot(stat="identity")`

plotted someone else's data correctly.

Comment: Well, I was just trying to nudge you in the direction of trying a simple first pass at debugging: set the column names in `allquartile` to something absolutely safe (no symbols).

Comment: `ymax='s.1000%'` may have an extra `0` and you seem to have a variety of ' and `

Comment: @Henry : Whoops, that's a typo for sure, but the problem still persists.   also, everything around the s.x% names are be backtics

Comment: @joran: I like that suggestion, but I'm 100% new to R (i've actually inheritted this code and am trying to extend it with boxplots).  How do I reset the column names in `allquartile`?

Comment: Use `colnames(allquartile) <- c(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, based on your edits, I think your real problem is that you shouldn't have been using `aggregate`. If the function you are applying returns multiple values (like `quantile`), `aggregate` returns the results in the somewhat inconvenient format you observed, by default.

What's happening is this. A data frame, somewhat confusingly, is actually a list, with each column being an element of the list. The only requirement being that each 'column' has the same number of rows. So you're getting a data frame back with three 'columns': the third column is a just a matrix!

Doing this with `aggregate` is possible, but there are more convenient tools out there. (For instance, you could call `cbind(allquartile[,1:2],allquartile[,3])` to create a data frame of the 'correct' dimensions.)

For example, a very popular one is `ddply` from the `plyr` package. Here's an example using some made up data, but following the general structure of your data:

```
topicquality <- data.frame(score = runif(20),
                            T = rep(letters[1:2],each = 10),
                            method = rep(letters[3:4],length.out = 20))

ddply(topicquality,.(T,method),FUN = function(x,...){quantile(x$score,...)},probs = seq(0,1,0.25))
```

You'll note that this will return a data frame of the dimensions you expect, but you still have to deal with the inconvenient column names. That's best dealt with in the function you apply to each piece:

```
myQuantile <- function(x,...){
    tmp <- quantile(x,...)
    names(tmp) <- NULL #Or something else convenient
    tmp
}
ddply(topicquality,.(T,method),FUN = myQuantile,probs = seq(0,1,0.25))
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I'm simply using aggregate since that's what was already written by someone else to plot simpler things like the mean, median, and max.  I managed to get things to work as stated above with aggregate and matrix operations, but I'll try giving this a spin.  I do find it pretty whacky that my third 'column' is a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to solve it. The issue is with your column names. If you type `names(allquartile)`, you will notice that your column names are `s.0.`, `s.25.` etc. My recommendation would to be avoid all punctuations in column names save for `_` or `.`.

```
require(stringr)
names(allquartile) = str_replace_all(names(allquartile), "\\.", '')
p <- ggplot(allquartile2, aes_string(x = "T", ymin = "s0", lower = "s25", 
      middle = "s50", upper = "s75", ymax = "s100", color = "method")) + 
     geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")
```